# VBA macro that clicks all the buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that clicks all the buttons in any document by getting all the buttons names and evaluating a call to these functions.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "b"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
MsgBox "a"
End Sub

Sub test_macro()
For Each S In Worksheets(1).OLEObjects
    Evaluate ("Call " + S.Name + "_Click")
Next
End Sub
```

What can be the problem here? and is there maybe another way to do it?

Comment: You cannot Evaluate a string of code like that in VBA.  Try `Application.Run` instead.

Comment: With 'Application.Run' it gives me Run-time error '1004' - "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: If you're having an issue with `Run` then maybe update your question with exactly how you tried it?

Comment: @cydan - Have you added reference to Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3 (Excel 2010)?

Comment: How do I add a reference to this? and I just used Run as I used Evaluate, the same way

Comment: In VBA IDE, Tools->Reference

Comment: @cydan Are your buttons Active X buttons or shapes?

Comment: The buttons are Active X. Now I added the reference for "...Applications Extensibility" and I get error code '438' when I try to run

Comment: You're doing `Run(S.Name + "_Click")`, right?

Comment: Tried it by doing Run(S.Name + "_Click"), still didn't work

Comment: It might not be seeing them because they're declared private. Try adding a public subroutine for each and alias them like `CommandButton1_Trigger`. All you need inside them is `Call CommandButton1_Click` since we're basically using them as a proxy to the private subroutines, which I believe need to be kept private or VBA might throw a fit.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to make a generic function that clicks the buttons without the knowledge of the buttons function names.. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Try qualifying your reference with the code name for the sheet `Application.Run Worksheets(1).CodeName & "." & S.Name & "_Click"`

Comment: [It looks like in order to click a button programmatically through VBA, you need to assign a boolean directly to the button object.](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/22555-can-visual-basic-applications-%22click%22-button.html#post2798876) Maybe you can have the function loop through all the buttons and assign them `True`? Try assigning True to `s`. If that doesn't work, use a numeric index loop instead along with the `OLEObjects.Items` collection and assigning `True` that way. For example, `OLEObjects.Items(1) = True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works.

```
For Each OLEObject In Worksheets(1).OLEObjects
    If TypeName(OLEObject.Object) = "CommandButton" Then OLEObject.Object = True
Next
```

[Here are some additional documentations on OLEObject.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobject-object-excel)